# How can I get rid of all errors: Cannot solve symbol.. from Binder.java class from android.os package?

Tags: java, android, android-binder

I'm trying to do the following thing:

`button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent startNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(startNextActivity);
    }
});`

but it gives me a null pointer in Binder.java line 404:

`01-19 20:17:00.859 1737-1749/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
    at 
    com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)`

At this line I found the following error: Cannot resolve method 'registerNativeAllocation(android.os.Binder, long)'.

I have a lot of errors like this one in Binder.java like: **Cannot resolve symbol 'ExceptionUtils'/ Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'**... 
How can I solve those errors?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Try doing: `Toolbar > Build > Clean Project` and then `Toolbar > Build > Rebuild Project` . Once that done try hitting the play button and see if it loads in the android emulator

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.. I still have the same errors..

Comment: I just realized I forgot to add the NextActivity to the AndroidManifest.xml file. The null pointer exception wasn't thrown any more.